# will com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(String src,String dst) over rides the existing file?

Tags: java, sftp

Hi I have a scenario where I need to download a set of files from two different locations which has the same name to my local machine.

Example:

- remote location one: user/temp1/sample.txt
- remote location two: user1/temp2/sample.txt
- local machine path: user3/temp3/

I am using java and com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(String src,String dst) method for performing this task. My doubt is, when I perform the 1st action which downloads the location one sample.txt file to my local folder and upon performing the second action which is to download the location two file to my same local folder. will the 1st downloaded file get's appended with the 2nd remote sample.txt file data or will it get's replaced with the new one or will it create a new file with the name sample(1).txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [javadoc](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you will see that for the `get(src, dest)` method the default mode is `OVERWRITE`, so **your first file by default will be overriden by the 2nd file**. The meaning of the different modes are:

- `OVERWRITE` - overwrite the existing file, if any.
- `RESUME` - resume an interrupted upload/download. This transfers only the part of the source file which is beyond the existing destination file's length.
- `APPEND` - file transfer mode: append to existing file, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the javaDoc link Gergely Basco. I could not find a way to change the mode to APPEND, I mean I did not find a method to change the mode like setMode(APPEND) or setMode(2) or get(src,dst,APPEND)? Can you route me to the correct way of doing this

Comment: You just need to use the right `get` method to achieve that. Something like:
`get(src, dst, null, 2);` // progressmonitor set to null, you don't need that & mode=2 means appending

Comment: It's `.put(src, dst, SftpChannel.APPEND)` for [`put(String src, String dst, int mode)`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-) *(comment re-posted with updated link, originally posted in Novermber 2015)*